# How do I give Vertex AI pipeline component permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

In a Vertex AI pipeline component,I try:

```
def my_comp(project_id: str, location: str, endpoint_id: str, endpoint: Output[Artifact]):
    import google.cloud.aiplatform as aip
    endpoints = aip.Endpoint.list()
...
```

which gives:

```
'aiplatform.endpoints.list' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/...
```

My service account has owner permissions, and it works outside of the component. What do I need to do?

Comment: Could you try this [code](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.endpoint_service.EndpointServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_endpoint_service_EndpointServiceClient_list_endpoints) to list endpoints and check whether your service account has these required [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control#predefined-roles)?

Comment: Hi, it can already list endpoints, just can't do it in the component.

Comment: Can you try using `from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform`?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I can't ge tthat to work  When I try `list_endpoints` I get: `google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 Received http2 header with status: 404
"`

Comment: Got it now. If you want to post this as an answer, I will accept it. Many thanks! @prajna-rai-t

Comment: Hi @schoon, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This permission denied on resource issue can be resolved by using import statement:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform
```